# Any way to align 2 dimensional arrays in Rubymine

Tags: ruby, arrays, formatting, rubymine

I'm working on a project where our data setup is similar to this:

```
data = [
   [:col1, :col2, :col3],
   [1, 1, 1], 
   [1, 2, 1], 
   [2, 1, 1]
]
```

With enough columns present, it starts to get unreadable.

I'd like it to look similar to this:

```
data = [
   [:col1, :col2, :col3],
   [    1,     1,     1], 
   [    1,     2,     1], 
   [    2,     1,     1]
]
```

Is there anyway to make Rubymine's autoformat to format arrays similar to the second example?

Comment: Asking for right align just for numbers is too much. That would require going pretty much into the semantics of the expression.